# How can I trim / remove part of a Tensor to match the shape of another Tensor with PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have 2 tensors:

```
outputs: torch.Size([4, 27, 161])       pred: torch.Size([4, 30, 161])
```

I want to cut `pred` (from the end) so that it'll have the same dimensions as `outputs`.

What's the best way to do it with PyTorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Narrow](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.narrow)

e.g:

```
a = torch.randn(4,30,161)
a.size() # torch.Size([4, 30, 161])
a.narrow(1,0,27).size() # torch.Size([4, 27, 161])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the fix number of dimensions of the two tensors, you can try this:

```
a = torch.randn(3, 5)
b = torch.zeros(3, 2)
b_h, b_w = b.shape
c = a[:b_h, :b_w]  # torch.Size([3, 2])
```

The `c` has the same shape as `b` but same values from `a`.